# Join date and time

Tags: r, date

Good Afternoon! I have data which consist of date and time of share price. I need to join this data to the one column.

```
        date  time   open   high    low  close
1 1999.04.08 11:00 1.0803 1.0817 1.0797 1.0809
2 1999.04.08 12:00 1.0808 1.0821 1.0806 1.0807
3 1999.04.08 13:00 1.0809 1.0814 1.0801 1.0813
4 1999.04.08 14:00 1.0819 1.0845 1.0815 1.0844
5 1999.04.08 15:00 1.0839 1.0857 1.0832 1.0844
6 1999.04.08 16:00 1.0842 1.0852 1.0824 1.0834
```

I tried to do that using this function:

```
df1 <- within(data, { timestamp = strptime(paste(date, time), "%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S") })
```

but I got the column of `NA`s.

Also I tried to do that using:

```
data$date_time = mdy_hm(paste(data$date, data$time))
```

but I got again the error:

> ```
> Warning message:
>     All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
> ```

Please, tell me what I do wrong.

Comment: Match your tokens and separators: `data$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(paste(data$date, data$time), format = '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')` or `lubridate::ymd_hm(paste(data$date, data$time))`

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, let's break it down first to see why you are getting `NA` values, and then generate a solution that creates your desired results.

```
> date <- c("1999.04.08", "1999.04.08")
> time <- c("11:00", "12:00")
> df <- data.frame(date, time, stringsAsFactors = F)
> df
        date  time
1 1999.04.08 11:00
2 1999.04.08 12:00
> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date: chr  "1999.04.08" "1999.04.08"
 $ time: chr  "11:00" "12:00"
```

Don't forget to use `str` to understand the data type(s) you are dealing with. That can and will greatly influence the answer to your question. Looking at the help description of function `strptime`, we see the following definition:

> `strptime` converts character vectors to class "POSIXlt": its input x is first converted by as.character. Each input string is processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored.

So, let's break down your code:

```
df1 <- within(data, 
        { timestamp = strptime(paste(date, time), 
                      "%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S") 
        })
```

First, the `paste` function:

```
> paste(date[1], time[1])
[1] "1999.04.08 11:00"
```

This generates a character vector with the format above.

Next, the `strptime` command.

```
> strptime(paste(date[1], time[1]), "%Y/%m/%d%H:%M:%S")
[1] NA
```

Okay, we see an NA. First, be sure to explicitly write `format =`, if it reads as tedious, then you should not be having any problems writing flawless code that you will remember forever. Looking at the help code we see:

```
x <- c("1jan1960", "2jan1960", "31mar1960", "30jul1960")
z <- strptime(x, "%d%b%Y")
> z
[1] "1960-01-01 PST" "1960-01-02 PST" "1960-03-31 PST" "1960-07-30 PDT"
```

Notice the help section also defines upper/lower case `Y`, and the same with the month and date variables. In your case, you are trying to extract something of the following form: `YYYY/mm/ddHH:MM:SS`, such as `2017/20/1111:28:30`. Do you see the issue now?

Using your string extraction attempt, we modify it slightly to get the format you are looking for:

```
> strptime(paste(date, time), format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M")
[1] "1999-04-08 11:00:00 PDT" "1999-04-08 12:00:00 PDT"
```

Putting it all together you get:

```
> df1 <- within(df, {timestamp = strptime(paste(date, time), format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M")})
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date     : chr  "1999.04.08" "1999.04.08"
 $ time     : chr  "11:00" "12:00"
 $ timestamp: POSIXlt, format: "1999-04-08 11:00:00" "1999-04-08 12:00:00"
> df1
        date  time           timestamp
1 1999.04.08 11:00 1999-04-08 11:00:00
2 1999.04.08 12:00 1999-04-08 12:00:00
```

Oh yeah, and try out the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
> df %>% 
  mutate(ts = as.POSIXct(paste(date,time), 
         format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M"))
        date  time                  ts
1 1999.04.08 11:00 1999-04-08 11:00:00
2 1999.04.08 12:00 1999-04-08 12:00:00
```

Comment: It was the great description. I understood my error. Thank you!!

Comment: Kamil, now I have the one question: I need the calculate difference between the first and second observation by ts variable: ts[2]-ts[1], but R prints that "The time difference of 1 hours. But how f.e. simplify this answer that R will print "1h" and no additional text?

Comment: There are a number of ways [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510044/how-to-make-time-difference-in-same-units-when-subtracting-posixct), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962278/dealing-with-timestamps-in-r), [3](https://blog.exploratory.io/5-most-practically-useful-operations-when-working-with-date-and-time-in-r-9f9eb8a17465), and more. A simple hack, and this is something you should replace with something more elegant in the future, is to wrap `as.numeric` around `difftime`. Try out `as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+1, units = "hours"))`